# Cant get input attr values in parent div

Tags: jquery, html, dom

i got this html code

```
<div class="main"><div class="labels"><p class="values"></p></div ></div>
<div id='tabs'>
<div>
    <div class="accordion">
        <div class="sub">
            <p><input type="checkbox" data="1" value="a"/> <label ></label></p>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
            <p><input type="checkbox" data="2" value="b"/> <label ></label></p>
        </div>
        <p><input type="checkbox" data="3" value="c"/><label></label></p>
        <p><input type="checkbox" data="4" value="d"/><label></label></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        labelsValue();
});         
function labelsValue(){
   var selected = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
      return $.trim($(this).attr('data'));
   }).get();
   $('.labels .values').text(selected.join(', '));
}
$('input').on('change', function() {
   labelsValue();
});
```

Tabs, ccordion, input values and attribute "data", a;bels are generated dynamic by php from arrays. I want to read data attr value form every input inside .accordion when checkbox is check/uncheck and display in p class="values" dynamic when input is check/uncheck .

But with this code, i have proper display values from data attr only from inputs inside div with class .sub. But it not work with inputs inside parent .accordion div. It displays only string with commas when i check those checkboxes, like that ", , , , ,".

How to fix it, i want the code to work with all children inputs inside .accordion div.

Help someone ?

Comment: you're missing **.on** after $('input'), it should read as **$('input').on('change', function() {})**;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delegate the event to the document:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
   labelsValue();
});
```

*because you have not put your change event in the document ready so this does not fire.*

Other way is to put it in the doc ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    labelsValue();

   $('input').on('change', function() { // <----put it here
        labelsValue();
   });
}); // <---end of doc ready
```

or a simplified way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    labelsValue();

   $('input').on('change', labelsValue);// <---put it here

}); // <---end of doc ready
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `on` function in jquery

```
 $('input').on('change', function() {
         labelsValue();
 });
```

instead of

```
 $('input')('change', function() {
        labelsValue();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$('input').on('change', function() {
            labelsValue();
        });
```

if your data coming dynamically try this approach.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
   labelsValue();
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M427C/3/)</kbd>

Comment: you missed .on "$('input')('change', function(){})"

Comment: Jes i missed in when copy the code to stack, $('input').on('change', function() { labelsValue(); }); is in the code and it didnt work for inputs in .accordion div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        labelsValue();
});         
function labelsValue(){
    var dataValue="";
   $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){



          if($(this).prop("checked")){

           dataValue +=$(this).attr('data')+',';

          }

        });

    $('.labels .values').text(dataValue);


}
$('input').change(function() {
   labelsValue();
});
```

JSFiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/tLS8M/6/